# How to make sure a website is still responsive when zoomed out?

Tags: html, css, position, zooming, responsive

I'm making a website with some "fancy" effects, but whenever I zoom out everything gets out of place. Are there any ways to fix this without using media queries? I'm having trouble understanding position relative and absolute. I've been researching for a while, but no matter what I try, it doesn't seem to work.

Everything looks out of place now, but the point is that you should be able to hover the sun, and then the effects will begin. However if you zoom out it doesn't stay in place.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #d37421;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
}


/* bakgrunn */

#siluette {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#slott {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 600px;
  width: auto;
  height: 500px;
}


/* dør */

#dor {
  position: absolute;
  left: 817px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 46px;
  height: 65px;
  top: 632px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#dor:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
}


/* måne*/

#maane {
  position: fixed;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: rgb(221, 22, 22);
  top: 60px;
  right: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 3s;
}

#maane:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}


/* vinduer */

#vindu1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  left: 650px;
  top: 565px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 380px;
  z-index: -2;
}

#vindu2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  left: 790px;
  top: 450px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#maane:hover~#vindu1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: 1s;
}

#maane:hover~#vindu2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: 1s;
}


/* tekst */

#tekst {
  position: absolute;
  top: 666px;
  left: 666px;
  color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: luminari, baskerville, sans-serif;
}


/* drakula */

#drakula {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  top: 520px;
  left: 635px;
  z-index: -20;
}

#maane:hover~#drakula {
  position: absolute;
  top: 330px;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="side1.css" ;>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">

    <!-- bakgrunn -->
    <img id="slott" src="https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/aa69e076-b797-4e7e-bcb7-5361856ae103/LWD8-castlemod.png" height="600px">
    <img id="siluette" src="https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/566a27be-83e1-4eee-a368-4640077fe5d5/0xb9-bakgrunn1.png">

    <!-- dør -->
    <a href="side2.html">
      <div id="dor"></div>
    </a>

    <!-- måne -->
    <div id="maane"></div>

    <!-- vinduer -->
    <div id="vindu1"></div>
    <div id="vindu2"></div>

    <!-- tekst -->
    <p id="tekst">Trykk på døren din djevel</p>

    <!-- drakula -->
    <img id=drakula src="https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/566a27be-83e1-4eee-a368-4640077fe5d5/4Bkm-dracula.png">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add meta tag in head.

```
<head>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot!

Comment: You are welcome @Mabero If you found this helpful, please like the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Getting to know what positions do is really important,

to get a more responsive website please use as much position relative as possible.

here's a guide on positions, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

I hope this guide will help u understand the positions better,

ps, making your website responsive?, consider using bootstrap: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_get_started.asp

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out those links

Comment: Just add a new comment or a new question if you still have a question after.

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap class for responsive...
like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and try to learn more from :

https://getbootstrap.com

https://bootswatch.com